# Inno Setup Check function for Dirs section

Tags: inno-setup

In the `Files` section you have the following possibility:

```
[Files]
Source: "Dir\File.ext"; DestDir: "{app}\Dir2"; Check: FileCheck('File.ext')
```

Is there a possibility to use a `Check` function for the `Dirs` section, such as below?

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\DirOnlyClientInstallation"; Check: DirCheck('Client')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your syntax is correct.

According to the [`Check` parameter documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

> ... is supported by **all sections** whose entries are separated into parameters.